# Getting the content to a mail message from a rule in applescript fails

Tags: email, applescript

I am trying to grab the body text of an email message (In this example I'm using the email subject to avoid any issues with text formatting) I'm sure this used to work:-

```
using terms from application "Mail"
 on perform mail action with messages theMessages
  tell application "Mail"
   activate
   set theMessage to item 1 of theMessages
   try
    set theMessageSubject to the subject of theMessage
   on error errMsg
    display dialog "Error: " & errMsg
   end try
  end tell
 end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from

RESULT -> Error: Can't get <<class mssg>> 1 of <<class mact>> "Incoming POP Messages" of <<class mact>> "My Email Account". Invalid Index.
```

I have also tried using "repeat with theMessage in theMessages" same result.

I've also tried inserting multiple delays because I read that that would help but it didn't here.

Comment: I've since discovered that this problem only occurs with POP messages. A work around is to use IMAP instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with how Apple Mail handles incoming POP messages. I am now using an IMAP account instead and that is an acceptable solution for me.